# How to cast a Newton.Json deserialized generic object to a custom object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am using Newton's Json.Net to deserialize Json to a .NET object. I am trying to understand whether one can cast from a general object to a specific object.

ie:

```
object myObject JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(myJsonValue);

myOrder = (Order)myObject;
```

The code is more about decribing my question. I understand that one could do this:

```
object myObject JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<order>(myJsonValue);
```

But due to the fact this is a helper function then it could not be "order", but something more general.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Getting the error:

```
Getting Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Order'
```

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand your question, but why not just use non-generic [version](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) if you still are going to cast?

Comment: By "helper function" do you mean the deserializing of JSON is in a helper function, so you don't know the concrete type at run time?

Comment: Yes thanks for this. Could be an easy fix. New to Json.net.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, the caller of the helper only knows the specific type, thus at present the helper can only generalise so that the caller can cast

Comment: @SamJolly: Can you post the source code for the helper function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to make an assumption here because the question isn't 100% clear, but I think I've got a good idea:

> But due to the fact this is a helper function then it could not be "order", but something more general.

You need to add a type argument to your helper function:

```
public class SomeHelper
{
    public T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
SomeHelper helper = new SomeHelper();
string json = "...";
Order order = helper.Deserialize<Order>(json);
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but this just replaces `JsonConvert` to `SomeHelper`... I guess the TO issue is a bit different

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin: I agree. Without seeing the source code for the "helper function" I'm not sure if this is the best solution, however the helper function may have additional logic in it.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Yes, maybe.

Comment: I put my error in my new EDIT. I think passing in T may be the answer. I will need to give it a try.

Comment: This was the approach I tool in the end, so a big thank you for this

Answer (score 5):

Rather than deserialize to an `object`, it's easier to work with something deserialized to `JToken`.

```
JToken myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(myJsonValue);
```

You can then use the `JToken.ToObject<T>()` method to perform the final conversion:

```
Order order = myObject.ToObject<Order>();
```

Comment: How is it better than a simple `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(myJsonValue)`

Comment: @L.B It's not always better, but sometimes it makes things easy, like using different types according to properties in the JSON value. Here is an example: https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/ac910fd2187dd1ec824ad2af3dda8c696d35d22b/src/corelib/Providers/Rackspace/Objects/LoadBalancers/HealthMonitor.cs#L136-L158

Comment: In the context of this question?

Comment: @L.B The question explicitly points out the syntax you mentioned, and states that it's not the desired solution. This is the alternative I would recommend.

Comment: @280Z28, Thank you for this. Did not know aout JToken before this, although I did going with the other approach.